# Prevent Shoes App Closed

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am currently building a simple App like an install wizard. At some steps the app will call an external batch script/bash script to execute some tasks on a separate Thread. I don't want the app be closed by the user during the external task execution. Is there any way to listen to the exit button of the window and prevent the event being processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method as of now as far as I can tell (and I maintain Shoes 4). However, I [added an issue in the issue tracker](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/issues/1158).